# Changing a boolean value in a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, boolean

I have a Job class which has a list of Tasks assigned to it. Everything is working fine, but I am trying to add a boolean field to mark a Job as complete. For now I am not checking all sub tasks. Just a simple check box that the Job is complete or not.

I have a data file that has predefined Jobs and Tasks in it. If I assign true or false to the complete variable in the data file, it all loads, the check boxes are populated, etc... but I can't change the value as it is hardcoded.

If I leave the value undefined I get a boolean expression must not be null error.

So in my Widget were I generate the list of Jobs (which can be pressed to show list of Tasks), I assume I need to initialize the complete variable before it renders the list. This Widget was a Stateless Widget before I added the boolean variable, I have changed it to Stateful as I am thinking I need to setState() to change the boolean variable. But since the Job is in data file this is where I am getting a bit stuck trying to assign or change the boolean variable.

Any pointers in what I am missing would be much appreciated.

```
class Job {
  int jobID;
  List<Task> task_list;
  String imageURL;
  String jobName;
  bool complete;

  Job({
   this.jobId,
   this.task_list,
   this.imageURL,
   this.jobName,
   this.complete,
  });

} 

class Task{
   int taskID;
   String imageURL;
   String name;
   String type;
   int taskTime;
   

  Task({
    this.taskID,
    this.imageURL,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.taskTime,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `Job` class constructor, could you change:

```
Job({
   this.jobId,
   this.task_list,
   this.imageURL,
   this.jobName,
   this.complete,
  });
```

to this:

```
Job({
   this.jobId,
   this.task_list,
   this.imageURL,
   this.jobName,
   this.complete = false,
  });
```

Giving `complete` a default value of `false` should avoid the `must not be null` error.  I assume this is OK since a job shouldn't be done by default, correct?

Comment: This, with an error I found has got it working, but since this is hard coded every time the app reboots the values return to false. Is there a way to do this and keep a Job as completed? Is this where I need to use Sql or Hive?

Comment: In the question you mention a data file, I'm assuming it's JSON, hardcoded somewhere in your Flutter project files?  And that we're deserializing this string map into `Job` and `Task` objects on startup?  After that, to save `Job` and `Task` objects as they change, yes, some sort of permanent storage, on-device like sqlite, hive, sembast, or even plain text file on device are possible solutions.  Off-device, over https could include firebase, hasura, etc.

Answer (score 0):

by any chance is the data file generated with `sqflite`? if yes, the `bool` type field must be changed to an `int` field using `0` and `1` for representing the `bool`

Comment: Thanks for the advice on this. I am not using SQL at the moment, but I think I will have to migrate to it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see changes on the widget, you have to surround the declaration with the `setState(() {complete = true});`